# How does Curry differs between Sanctuary and Ramda?

Tags: javascript, sanctuary

I am stuck with the curry examples in "Professor's Frisby..." when using Sanctuary instead of Ramda. I get error: "‘curry2’ expected at most three arguments but received five arguments." while with Ramda works fine. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Following the book's example:

```
var match = curry2((what, str) => {return str.match(what);});
var hasSpaces = match(/\s+/g);
var filter = curry2((f, ary) => {return ary.filter(f);});
var f2 = filter(hasSpaces, ["tori_spelling", "tori amos"]);
```

I get

```
TypeError: Function applied to too many arguments
curry2 :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
‘curry2’ expected at most three arguments but received five arguments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanctuary is much stricter than Ramda. It ensures that functions are only ever applied to the correct number of arguments and that the arguments are of the expected types. `S.add(42, true)`, for example, is a type error, whereas `R.add(42, true)` evaluates to `43`.

The problem in your case is that [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) applies the given function to three arguments (`element`, `index`, `array`). `hasSpaces`, though, expects exactly one argument.

The solution is to use [`S.filter`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#filter) rather than `Array#filter`:

```
const match = S.curry2((what, str) => str.match(what));
const hasSpaces = match(/\s+/g);
const f2 = S.filter(hasSpaces, ['tori_spelling', 'tori amos']);
```

Having made this change, another type error is revealed:

```
TypeError: Invalid value

filter :: (Applicative f, Foldable f, Monoid f) => (a -> Boolean) -> f a -> f a
                                                         ^^^^^^^
                                                            1

1)  null :: Null

The value at position 1 is not a member of ‘Boolean’.

See https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-def/tree/v0.12.1#Boolean for information about the Boolean type.
```

`S.filter` expects a predicate as its first argument. In strict terms a predicate is a function which returns either `true` or `false`. [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), though, returns either `null` or an array of matches.

The solution is to use [`S.test`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#test) rather than `String#match`:

```
const hasSpaces = S.test(/\s+/);
const f2 = S.filter(hasSpaces, ['tori_spelling', 'tori amos']);
```

At this point the definition of `hasSpaces` is so clear that there's not much value in giving it a name. We can write the code as a single expression:

```
S.filter(S.test(/\s/), ['tori_spelling', 'tori amos'])
```

Note that the pattern can be simplified from `/\s+/g` to `/\s/`. The `g` flag has no effect when using `S.test`, and the `+` isn't necessary since we're interested in strings with spaces but we're not interested in counting the spaces.

Comment: Thanks davidchambers for such a thorough answer!